# implode terms to class

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm stuck getting terms into a list and class at the same time. I can return the list no problem, but I need the slug to also be the class.
Here is my code

```
$terms = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'events17groups' );
if ($terms && ! is_wp_error($terms)) :
$tslugs_arr = array();
foreach ($terms as $term) {
    $tslugs_arr[] = $term->slug;
}
endif;
    $listclass = implode(" ", $tslugs_arr);
    $listgroup = "<li class='$listclass'>" . implode("</li><li 
class='$listclass'>", $tslugs_arr) . "</li>";
    echo "<ul class='eventgroup'>$listgroup</ul>";
```

This produces the following HTML

```
<ul class="eventgroup"><li class="exhibitions home">exhibitions</li><li 
class="exhibitions home">home</li></ul>
```

So what I want is

```
<ul class="eventgroup"><li class="exhibitions">exhibitions</li><li 
class="home">home</li></ul>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried separating the strings using a comma rather than white space?

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a simple readable `foreach`:

```
$listgroup = '';
foreach ($tslugs_arr as $item) {
    $listgroup .= '<li class="' . $item . '">' . $item . '</li>';
}
echo "<ul class='eventgroup'>$listgroup</ul>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried like this?

```
$terms = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'events17groups' );
if ($terms && ! is_wp_error($terms)) :
$tslugs_arr = array();
foreach ($terms as $term) {
    $tslugs_arr[] = $term->slug;
}
endif;
    $listclass = implode(" ", $tslugs_arr);
    $listgroup = "<li class='".tslugs_arr[0]."'>" . implode("</li><li 
class='".tslugs_arr[1]."'>", $tslugs_arr) . "</li>";
    echo "<ul class='eventgroup'>$listgroup</ul>";
```

Comment: Please explain every answer that you post.

Comment: Yes I'll add more elaborately how it works?. Now I'm on mobile, I'll do as soon as I sit on my pc, thanks for pointing me out. You're a Master :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do a fancy one-liner then try out:

```
<?php
$terms = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'events17groups' );
if ($terms && ! is_wp_error($terms)) :
    $tslugs_arr = array();
    foreach ($terms as $term) {
        $tslugs_arr[] = $term->slug;
    }
endif;

echo "<ul class='eventgroup'>".implode('', array_map( function( $tslug ){ return "<li class='$tslug'>$tslug</li>"; }, $tslugs_arr ) )."</ul>";
```